# Is it possible to send a command from one cmd-window to another (already existing) cmd-window?

Tags: cmd, command, command-prompt, prompt

Is it possible to send a command from one cmd-window to another (already existing and opened) cmd-window?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is.

I would recommend taking a look at Sockets, cause that would probably be the easiest way of doing this.

Comment: I had try out these two c-programs from this site: http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/unixsock.html. For the server prog I get these output: "Waitting for Connection". For the other one commes: "Trying to connect" and "connect: No such file or directory". What can I do?

Comment: Sorry, have not used unixsock and it would probably take longer time for me to read up on it enough to be able to give you support than for you to either debug it yourself or get help from someone else! Good luck :)

Comment: Thanks a lot anyway. The socket-theme is what I have searched for.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the fact that linux opens up a new console device, which can be retrieved using the `tty` command. So you can do:

```
echo 'some text' > '/dev/pts/19'
```

(assuming that the other window's tty is `/dev/pts/19`).

You can print also to your current window:

```
echo 'some text' > `tty`
```

though it's not of much use :)

EDIT: I've just read that you want to send commands, not just text. In this case you could try to play with the above solution & Bash's `read` function: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/commands/builtin/read with something like

```
while read data; do; eval $data; done
```

combined with file descriptors, probably.

Comment: Is it possible to write a Unix-Script that deal with commands like socket(), bind() ans so on? There are many tutorials for this for languages like c, python and java. The Problem is: I didnt find this for Unix-Shell-Scripting! You suggestion is very good. But for realizing this, I need a tutorial for server-client-programming in Unix-Shell-Scripting. Have you any Ideas?

Comment: It would really be best option, to realize the connection only with Unix-Shell-Scripting. Without any other languages. Do you think, this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, which uses cmd, you can use `SENDKEYS` (Via a VBS script) to write commands to another window, and `AutoIt` can also script GUI's and other program windows.